# Which is the least stable trihalide of nitrogen?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, stability, halides, pnictogen

Which is the least stable trihalide of nitrogen and why?
I have two conflicting theories, one is that fluorine-fluorine electron repulsion will make $\ce{NF3}$ least stable and another is steric reasons of iodine which give $\ce{NI3}$ as the answer.

Which is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Nitrogen triiodide $\ce{NI3}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen_triiodide) is an extremely sensitive explosive that explodes with the slightest touch when dry.

[Nitrogen trifluoride $\ce{NF3}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen_trifluoride) is so stable that it is a greenhouse gas global warming concern, with lifetime in the atmosphere of hundreds of years.

$\ce{NI3}$ is unstable due to steric strain as you are saying.

Comment: I agree with Dave's answer, but would add that iodoform ($\ce{CHI3}$) is stable.  I suspect that $\ce{NI3}$ is unstable due to sterics **and** an extremely exothermic pathway leading to the formation of the very stable $\ce{N#N}$ triple bond.  A similar decomposition pathway does not exist for iodoform, hence its relative stability.

Comment: I could be wrong about the reason, since NCl3 is also unstable.

Comment: I believe something's rather different about the fluorine compounds. Even sulfur hexafluoride and carbon tetrafluoride are extremely stable. I guess it's by virtue of their high bond strengths.